# Angular2 template driven forms: how to create field validation for a custom form control?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to create a custom form control that handles any errors on itself. This means showing the error inside this component. I created a component which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. I can read the error form the form like this: `form.controls.myfieldname.errors.aErrorName` so I pass `form.controls.myfieldname` to my constom control.

Is there a better way to create field validation for a custom form control?

My custom control:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-text2',
    templateUrl: './input-text2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['/input-base2.scss', './input-text2.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: InputText2Component }
    ]
})
export class InputText2Component implements ControlValueAccessor {
    // The control field: form.controls.fieldname
    @Input() field;

    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() errorMessage: string;

    value: string;
    valueChange: (value: any) => void;
    _onTouched: (value: any) => void;


    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.value = value;
        this.createClasses(this.size);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void): void {
        this.valueChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: (value: any) => void): void {
        this._onTouched = fn;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<div  *ngIf="field?.errors && field?.touched">
    invalid
</div>
```

Form:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm">
    <input-text2 [field]="form.controls.fieldname" name="fieldname" errorMessage="My error message" label="My label"  [(ngModel)]="model"
        custom-validator>
    </input-text2>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer

I added this to my control:

```
private ngControl: NgControl;

constructor(private injector: Injector) {

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
}
```

`ngControl` is now basically the same as my `field` property. Next I could remove `field` completely and replace is with `ngControl`.